# Grails Paging Results are Inconsistent

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, paging

I'm doing some paging in my Grails application.  Since I'm doing some special sorting, I can't use the convient sort/paging methods.  Here is my paging code on the server side:

```
def criteria = ClientContact.createCriteria().createAlias("client", "c")
criteria.setFirstResult(params.offset?.toInteger())
criteria.setMaxResults(params.max?.toInteger())
def sortField = params.sort
if(params.sort == "clientName") sortField = "c.name"
criteria.addOrder(params.order == "asc" ? Order.asc(sortField) : Order.desc(sortField))
            /*
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(params.searchField))
            {
                criteria.add(
                    Restrictions.or (
                        Restrictions.ilike("c.name", "%" + params.searchField + "%"),
                        Restrictions.or(
                            Restrictions.ilike("firstName", "%" + params.searchField + "%"),
                            Restrictions.ilike("lastName", "%" + params.searchField + "%")
                        )
                    )
                )
            }
                */

def results = criteria.list()
```

You'll notice the section of code commented-out.  Typically, it would be uncommented so I can do my special sorting, but it's commented-out to help reduce the number of variables causing this problem.

When I look at the 4th page of my results, I see a certain list of people.  When I reload the 4th page of results, I see a slightly different list -shifted by 8 people.

Does anyone have any idea why I would be receiving inconsistent results?  I would expect to get the same 100 people every time I view the 4th page of my results (If you haven't guess, I'm showing people's names).  The 'offset,' 'max,' and 'sort' values are identical across both requests.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks,

Andrew

Update....

Here is the more straightforward approach that should work, except I receive an exception.  If I remove the 'createAlias' line, I don't receive the exception.  Unfortunately, I need the alias to join to an associated table.

```
            if(params.sort == 'client') params.sort = 'c.name'
            def criteria = ClientContact.createCriteria()
            criteria.createAlias('client', 'c')
            def pagedResults = criteria.list(offset: params.offset, max: params.max, sort: params.sort, order: params.order ?: 'asc' ) {
                    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(params.searchField)) {
                            or {
                                            ilike "c.name", "%$params.searchField%"
                                            ilike "firstName", "%$params.searchField%"
                                            ilike "lastName", "%$params.searchField%"
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Exception:

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   call to [list] not supported here
>
> at
>   grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:847)
>
> at
>   ClientContactController$_closure21_closure39_closure44.doCall(ClientContactController:494)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea why the sorting is inconsistent across different request, but I'd like to show you the "default" grails approach for your code:

```
if(params.sort == 'clientName') params.sort = 'c.name'
def criteria = ClientContact.createCriteria()
criteria.createAlias('client', 'c')
def results = criteria.list( sort: params.sort, order: params.order ?: 'asc' ) {
    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(params.searchField)) {
        or {
            ilike "c.name", "%$params.searchField%"
            ilike "firstName", "%$params.searchField%"
            ilike "lastName", "%$params.searchField%"
        }
    }
}
```

the results variable is then an instance of PagedResultList, which is basically a normal list, but has a "totalCount" property to ease the paging.

Comment: This won't work for me because I need an alias to an associated table.  Since ClientContact has a Client object associated with it, if I want to sort a ClientContact by its Client.Name, I need to create an alias for the Client table.  That's why I ended up using the Hibernate criteria builder.

Comment: I would expect your code to work, but I can't get it to compile.  I've updated my original post.  You can see how I implemented your example.  I've also included the exception I receive.  But I agree with you that this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you. When you call `.list()` you gonna throw this error on `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`:

```
if (this.criteria != null) {
    this.throwRuntimeException(new IllegalArgumentException("call to [" + name + "] not supported here"));
}
```

The problem is that you are calling `.list` in an instance that already has `criteria` set. The solution would be to use something like @siegfried-puchbauer suggested, with some differences:

```
ClientContact.createCriteria().list(sortingParamsAsMap) {
    // You need to put ALL your criteria inside this closure
    createAlias("client", "c")

    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(params.searchField)) {
        or {
            ilike "c.name", "%$params.searchField%"
            ilike "firstName", "%$params.searchField%"
            ilike "lastName", "%$params.searchField%"
        }
    }
}
```

The difference on the other approach is that even the `createAlias` method must be inside the `list` closure. You can't have anything before this.